# how to convert multiple 'tags' into numerical value

Tags: tags, random-forest, numeric

Suppose I have this table of movies with several ratings including mine. I want to use (let's say) a random forest on that table to teach the machine which movies could be good for me. Now, for each movie I have several writer involved and I want to take this data into account. Abstractly speaking we can see them as **tags**: for a row of the table I can have any number of tags, and one tag can appear in several rows.
My question is **how do I convert this into numbers**?

*From what I learn in sklearn so far, an obvious way would be to use .dummies method and create one column for each tag and put a one if the writer is involved or a zero if not.
Is this the correct way? I mean I get quite a lot of column in this way, is this a problem for let's say a random forest? Is there an other way?*

I was not able to find any answer online that fits my doubt. I am starting to think that the obvious way is the correct way, that's why I don't find anything.. But I cannot be sure.